Error "Failed to connect to <IP>" when connecting AWS Redshift with DevExpress
I'm trying to connect my AWS Redshift serverless to DevExpress Grid, but I have the following error: "Failed to connect to IP". Honestly, I don't understand where this IP comes from since if I deactivate the "Publicly accessible" configuration of the work-group it changes to the IPv4 CIDR of the associated VPC. (The screenshot is taken with "Publicly accessible" on, but with it off the error is the same, just different IP).

I have also set all IPv4 accessible inbound and outbound rules of the VPC security group. Nothing has changed.
Do you have any idea about what is the problem here?
I also tried to ping the IP returned by the error, and it seems not to respond.
